# Asp with Apache on Solaris, I´m so confused!

Tags: apache, asp-classic, solaris

I am studying for an exam and I dont know how to solve this question:

*A developer has been engaged to set up a databasedriven web site in which content is to be entered via a web-based form into a MS-SQL Database. The publicfacing web pages for retrieving the data and populating a template would be in .ASP. The Web Server being used is Apache running on a Sun Solaris Operating System. Draw a flow chart to illustrate the set-up.
Would the developer need any additional software to complete the development of the proposed site? If so, what is required, and where would it be in the dataflow?*

I dont need the full answer, just some hints to keep on solving it myself.

Thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: ASP? You mean...Active Server Pages? In Apache? In Solaris? I suggest you first start searching for information about ASP and Apache server. Do you have to put MS-SQL on Solaris too? (Not possible) :p Note that this setup is very weird. Most of it is actually possible on the operating system given, at least from a hypothetical standpoint. From a reality standpoint, I have not heard of such a configuration.

Comment: Well for hosting the asp pages you can start here:
 http://ns7.webmasters.com/caspdoc/ 
As far as sql server on Solaris, I'm at a loss

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Sun ONE Active Server Pages](http://www.sun.com/download/products.xml?id=420a8e72) to get Classic ASP to work on Apache on Solaris, but MS-SQL... I have to assume you'd need to connect to a remote IIS server which is running it.

Comment: ¿No more questions regarding the diagram? Thanks